# Muxing multiple JPEG into a JXL animation

Tags: ffmpeg, jpeg-xl

Using ffmpeg I can [mux](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/7913/10558) multiple JPEG into a M-JPEG container without any loss since it is a just a plain bitstream copy:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 30 -i input%03d.jpg -codec copy output.mjpeg
```

Recently linux distributions started to offer JPEG-XL command line tools. I can now recode (lossless recompression) of JPEG into JXL:

```
% file input.jpg
input.jpg: JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01, aspect ratio, density 1x1, segment length 16, baseline, precision 8, 1016x708, components 3
% cjxl input.jpg output.jxl
% djxl output.jxl output.jpg
% md5sum input.jpg output.jpg
bea9e9c74e3580f6196ba9ac21509652  input.jpg
bea9e9c74e3580f6196ba9ac21509652  output.jpg
```

However I fail to understand how to create a JXL animation (more than one JPEG) ?

Eg:

```
% ffmpeg -framerate 30 -i input%03d.jpg -codec copy output.jxl
[...]
[image2 @ 0x55c22e680040] The specified filename 'output.jxl' does not contain an image sequence pattern or a pattern is invalid.
[image2 @ 0x55c22e680040] Use a pattern such as %03d for an image sequence or use the -update option (with -frames:v 1 if needed) to write a single image.
[image2 @ 0x55c22e680040] Cannot write more than one file with the same name. Are you missing the -update option or a sequence pattern?
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Invalid argument
frame=    2 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:00.06 bitrate=N/A speed= 223x
video:224kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
Conversion failed!
```

Or:

```
% cjxl input*.jpg output.jxl
Unknown argument: input002.jpg
Use 'cjxl -h' for more information
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: I don't the ability to do this is exposed in the existing tools (yet), but the code library code itself looks promising (but requires making a custom utility or possible a significant addition to the `jcxl` utility).

I would consider opening a feature request/issue on this.

---

As of writing this answer the jxl reference implementation for cjxl the real work starts with the entry point `EncodeImageJXL(params, ppf, jpeg_bytes, &compressed);`
where `jpeg_bytes` is optional (may be `nullptr`, and only represents a single image) and otherwise the image data (which could contain multiple frames) is otherwise part of `ppf`.

After some initial setup this function [splits logic based on this optional `jpeg_bytes`](https://github.com/libjxl/libjxl/blob/e6202f7181eff36c78bfdb79aa9bd45c3d1d614b/lib/extras/enc/jxl.cc#L85) where it will either use the where it will either use the provided single jpeg bytes directly via `JxlEncoderAddJPEGFrame` or loop over each frame in `ppf.frames` and call `JxlEncoderAddImageFrame` for each frame decompressed *pixel data*.

There is also a fair number setup and settings that differ between these code paths, and I have a hard time differentiating what what is necessarily related to animation of what is just a result of doing full compression rather than just re-compressing the jpeg data.

Unfortunately, there is currently no way to use `cjxl` to even select multiple input files for `cjxl` right now, and I don't think `ffmpeg` exposes a way to select the necessary `JxlEncoderAddJPEGFrame` encoding at all. But the code does suggest to me that it should be possible by picking out the necessary setup from each code path and calling `JxlEncoderAddJPEGFrame` for each jpeg file data.
Perhaps this could be made part of `cjxl`; most of the work would be to make it safe (checking that all images are jpegs, checking similar sizes, adding options for framerate etc.).

I could be missing some fundamental limitation in the jxl bytestream which means this type of lossless re-compression isn't supported, but seeing as there isn't any inter-prediction I'm hopeful that this is supported.

Comment: https://github.com/libjxl/libjxl/issues/2727